# Gradient of a norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can I compute the gradient of $||y||^6$?

Can I rewrite it as $(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^3$ and then $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y_i} (\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^3 = 6y_i^5 + 6y_i(\sum_{j \neq i} y_j^2)^2 + 12y_i^3 \sum_{j \neq i} y_j^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin in the same way as you, but continue as

$$\frac {\Bbb d f} {\Bbb d y_i} \left( \sum _{i=1} ^n y_i ^2 \right)^3 = 3 \left( \sum _{i=1} ^n y_i ^2 \right)^2 \frac {\Bbb d f} {\Bbb d y_i} \left( \sum _{i=1} ^n y_i ^2 \right) = 6 y_i \| y \| ^4 ,$$

so $\nabla \| y \|^6 = 6 \| y \|^4 y$.

In general, you have $\nabla \| y \|^{2a} = 2a \| y \|^{2(a-1)} y$ for $a \ne 0$.